# Optimising an iterrows loop with multiple column references in Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
for index, row in data2.iterrows():
  date_selection = (data1['Start Time'] > row['shifted_date']) & (data1['Start Time'] <= row['Timestamp'])
  relevant_data = data1.loc[date_selection]
  data2.loc[index, 'Relevant_Duration_Sum'] = relevant_data['Duration'].sum()
```

Hi Everyone,

I'm trying to run a loop over a large dataset as shown above and wants to optimise this loop.
I've been trying to convert it to a function to use with `.apply`, however I'm really stuck as `apply` loops over one column at a time instead of one row at a time and I'm referring to multiple columns and making an assignment in the last line.

I'm really stuck at this and any suggestions would really help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code. (I couldn't check the output since there was no data available)

```
def relevant_duration_sum(_shifted_date, _timestamp):
  rel_duration_sum = data1.loc[(data1['Start Time'] > _shifted_date) & (data1['Start Time'] <= _timestamp), 'Duration'].sum()
  return rel_duration_sum

data2['Relevant_Duration_Sum'] = data1.apply(lambda x: relevant_duration_sum(x['Shifted_date'], x['Timestamp']), axis=1)
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thank you! Worked great and cut down the processing time significantly. I made a slight edit to your answer to correct a df reference.